CSS Grid Item height collapsing
With this CSS
body {
  height: 100%;
}
.container {
  position: absolute;
  border: 1px dashed red;
  left: 10px;
  top: 10px;
  height: 400px;
  width: 400px;
  display: grid;
  overflow: auto;
}
.vrt-text {
  border: 1px dotted blue;
  overflow: auto;
  display: flex;
  justify-content: flex-end;
}

p {
  font-family: Georgia, serif;
  font-size: 18px;
}
   
.vertical-rl {
  writing-mode: vertical-rl;
  color: #0074d9;
  margin: 0 6px;
}

and this HTML
<div class="container" style="top: 450px">
  <p>Text 1</p>
  <div class="vrt-text">
    <p class="vertical-rl">Text 2</p>
  </div>
  <p>Text 3</p>
  <p>Text 4</p>
  <p>Text 5</p>
  <p>Text 6</p>
  <div class="vrt-text">
    <p class="vertical-rl">Text 7</p>
    <p class="vertical-rl">Text 8</p>
  </div>
  <p>Text 9</p>
  <div class="vrt-text">
    <p class="vertical-rl">Text 10</p>
  </div>
  <p>Text 11</p>
  <div class="vrt-text">
    <p class="vertical-rl">Text 12</p>
    <p class="vertical-rl">Text 13</p>
    <p class="vertical-rl">Text 14</p>
    <p class="vertical-rl">Text 15</p>
  </div>
  <p>Text 16</p>
</div>

The height div.vrt-text collapses to 0 but the p elements not within a div.vrt-text maintain their height:

I think what's happening is that as the vertical space becomes smaller the vertical text within div.vrt-text wraps (which is fine) but there's nothing to stop the height from collapsing to 0.
I need .vrt-text to be display: flex so I can have multiple vertical text itmes next to each other and not go one under the other.
How can I have all the text readable without setting specific heights/sizes for items?

Why do you need overflow: auto for .vrt-text? If I remove it it prevents from the collapse to height 0.


body {
  height: 100%;
}

.container {
  position: absolute;
  border: 1px dashed red;
  left: 10px;
  top: 10px;
  height: 400px;
  width: 400px;
  display: grid;
  overflow: auto;
}

.vrt-text {
  border: 1px dotted blue;
  /* overflow: auto; */
  display: flex;
  justify-content: flex-end;
}

p {
  font-family: Georgia, serif;
  font-size: 18px;
}

.vertical-rl {
  color: #0074d9;
  margin: 0 6px;
}
<div class="container" style="top: 0px">
  <p>Text 1</p>
  <div class="vrt-text">
    <p class="vertical-rl">Text 2</p>
  </div>
  <p>Text 3</p>
  <p>Text 4</p>
  <p>Text 5</p>
  <p>Text 6</p>
  <div class="vrt-text">
    <p class="vertical-rl">Text 7</p>
    <p class="vertical-rl">Text 8</p>
  </div>
  <p>Text 9</p>
  <div class="vrt-text">
    <p class="vertical-rl">Text 10</p>
  </div>
  <p>Text 11</p>
  <div class="vrt-text">
    <p class="vertical-rl">Text 12</p>
    <p class="vertical-rl">Text 13</p>
    <p class="vertical-rl">Text 14</p>
    <p class="vertical-rl">Text 15</p>
  </div>
  <p>Text 16</p>
</div>




The thing that cause the issue is having writing-mode: vertical-rl; in .vertical-rl.

no, it didn't have any effect.

It does for me so I don't know why it doesn't for you. At any rate I'm moving away from using a grid as it a would mean changes to (what my manager says) is too much other code.
